# Rotating a UIView incrementally based on its x location on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, rotatetransform

I would like to rotate an `UIImageView` by 90 degrees over the span of the length of the iPhone's view using `imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);`, and was wondering how I could implement this as the view is being dragged left by the user (and thus also the ability to rotate "back" if the view is dragged right).  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you having trouble with? Dragging the view? Change position/rotation?

Comment: @ssantos I added an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and so dragging works.  However, what I am having trouble figuring out is how to add the `UIImageView` transformations while the user is dragging, as well as rotating back the view if the user pans right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding moving the view, you can do so by updating its `frame` property like this.-

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + xOffset, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

You may also add and `observer` that listens to your `view` `frame` changes.-

```
[view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

Here, you basically are asking for receiving a notification whenever the property `frame` of object `view` changes. You can handle that notification implementing the following method.-

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
        // Change object rotation depending on frame.origin.x
    }
}
```

You'll have to do some maths to calculate rotation based on `x` position. Also, I guess rotating the view along its center is a little tricky, maybe you'll find the post below useful.-

http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Rotating-an-iPhone-View-Around-a-Point

The thing is, you won't have to worry about wherever you're panning to, as view rotation will just get update according to its position everytime it changes.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks - will give this a go tonight!